# Disable track on HTML5 range input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, range

I'm trying to find a way to prevent the user from clicking into the "track" portion of an HTML5 range input. Essentially, I only want the user to be able to use the "handle" to change the range value.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I think your best bet for that amount of customization might be an existing "widget framework" where they've made their own slider  intended for browsers that don't support input-ranges by default. I couldn't suggest which one to use though.

Comment: using jquery to disable go and check
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/47384010/7439186">check here </a>

Answer (score 6):

It's possible through pointer-events at least on chrome.

```
input[type=range] {
pointer-events: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
pointer-events:auto;
}
```

This will disable clicking on the track and enable clicking only on slider thumbs.

Comment: Agreed. This actually works and it's a simple way to do it as well

Comment: Except it doesn't appear to work any longer.
Using Chrome v62.0.3202.94 on Windows 10, and setting these properties either in CSS as above, or via JQuery as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647573/disable-track-click-on-input-type-range/47384010#47384010 no longer appears to disable the track.

Setting disabled on the input tag, as torresomar suggested, disables the entire widget not just the track.

Answer (score 1):

Adding disabled should work.

```
<input id="rangeindicator" disabled type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10">
```

and then you can easily change the values using jQuery, like this:

```
$("#rangeindicator").val(1)
```