# ionic range input prevents scrolling

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have bunch of sliders stacked vertically in my application. When I tap on the slider with an intention to scroll down or up, it changes the slider value instead of scrolling.

[See a demo of the issue](http://play.ionic.io/m/9cc859020ea0).

The following are the discussions among community members but I found nothing helpful there:

1. [This reported issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3897) which is same as this question but somehow author is convinced upon using [angular-js-slider](https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider) library and looks like it works  for the author. I tried this library and issue is still the same.
2. [Reported issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1078) with all input elements and not just range input. May be this resolved the issue with other input types like `"text"` but not for range input.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On web, scrolling is definitely not an issue but on mobile devices, the entire horizontal span of the slider acts as a barrier to scroll.

Since I was looking for the solution in mobile context, disabling the track for any mouse event looks sufficient to me and this can be achieved through `pointer-events`, at least on chrome.

```
input[type=range] {
  pointer-events: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events:auto;
}
```

The answer posted here has been [contributed earlier here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29148163/2060248).