# Disable track click on input type range

Tags: css, html

I want to disable track click on input type range, Only allow drag through thumb.

I am able to do it in all browsers except Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer.

I am doing this way

```css
#slider {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  z-index: 20;
  border-radius: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}

#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}

#slider::-ms-thumb {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}

#slider::-ms-track {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" autocomplete="off" />
```

Please see why its not working on Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer and suggest any possible way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: I'm **very curious** to why would you want that.

Comment: You can do that if you use a third-party script which emulate the `range` functionality and is customizable enough to allow disabling the rack clicking.

Answer (score -1):

using jquery
to disable

> $("input[name=Range]").css("pointer-events","none");
>   $("input[name=Range]").css("disabled","disabled");

to normal

> $("input[name=Range]").css("pointer-events","auto");
>   $("input[name=amountRange]").removeAttr("disabled");