# Disable track of range sliders in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I would like to prevent users from klicking directly on the track of a range element to specify a value and only allow them to drag the slider. This works perfectly fine in all browsers except from IE and Edge, using the following CSS code:

```
#slider {pointer-events: none}

#slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}
#slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}
#slider::-ms-thumb {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}
#slider::-ms-track {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

I then follow advice from following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647573/disable-track-click-on-input-type-range?noredirect=1&lq=1) and additionally enter the code below in the JS Editor in Qualtrics:

```
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=Range]").css("pointer-events","none");
    $("input[name=Range]").css("disabled","disabled");
});
```

However, this does unfortunately not change the behavior of clicking on the track in IE and Edge. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: don't you mean input[type=range]? (not the name attribute). You can disable event handlers by using an inline event handler... eg> <input type="range" onclick="return false;" onchange="update_value(event);"/>, range and other elements are drawn using SVG.... the track and thumb do not inherit the event handlers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, this does not work. Adding <input type="range" onclick="return false;" onchange="update_value(event);"/> and deleting the css/jquery code does not change the behavior in Chrome, Firefox etc. However, behavior in IE changes but in the wrong way. Sliders can now be clicked but no longer dragged, which is exactly the opposite of what I want. Am I doing something wrong?