# How to disable touch on input range only accept drag to change its value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML input as a type of `range`. Users can change its value by dragging the thumb. But users can also change its value by touching the track area which brings the thumb there directly. How can I disable the touching change value and only enable dragging?

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" />
```

If the thumb is on the "0" position, users can touch the middle of the input which moves the thumb around 50. I want to disable users touch on the track of the input and only allow users to drag the thumb to change its value.

Comment: Can you provide code and the current behavior? and what you want to disable?

Comment: I updated my question. Could you let me know whether it makes sense?

Comment: It made sense to me even before you updated it. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do what you want to do except to implement your own range input

Comment: can you use jquery or need it on plan js?

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/a/29148163/7124761

Comment: @PrashantPimpale we were literally looking at the same link haha that's funny :) happy coding

Comment: @PatricioVargas Yes Exactly, that why I posted the link but the answer was not accepted at the posted question so posted an answer

Comment: Sorry for confusing all. My question was answered and I am happy for this solution. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly then might be what you are looking for is:

```css
input[type=range] {
pointer-events: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
pointer-events:auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" />
```

Answer (score 3):

**Your CSS** This works on chrome

```
input[type=range] {
 pointer-events: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 pointer-events:auto;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a working solution for Internet Explorer/Edge?